# Is modus ponens inherently circular?

Tags: logic, fallacies

Consider this simple argument for why Socrates is mortal:

```
All men are mortal.
Socrates is a man.
Thus, Socrates is mortal.
```

This argument can be roughly formalized as follows:

```
IF P THEN Q
R
R≡P
Q
```

where P is "man," Q is "is mortal," and R is "Socrates." This argument bears a resemblance to the typical modus ponens argument:

```
IF P THEN Q
P
Q
```

Here is an another example from [this Wikipedia page on begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question):

```
God possesses all the virtues.
Benevolence is a virtue.
Therefore, God is benevolent.
```

It makes me wonder if modus ponens is inherently circular because the first premise `IF P THEN Q` immediately implies conclusion `Q`. If all circular arguments are fallacious, can modus ponens argument be considered fallacious in this sense?

Comment: It's less a matter of fallacies, more a matter of *triviality*, dependent on the complexity of the conditional premise and argument, and its subpremises.

Comment: No, it's not circular. "If P then Q" does not imply Q.

Comment: This question is closely related to another recent one: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/104220/do-you-gain-further-truth-from-syllogisms See my answer to that. Deductively valid arguments are not automatically question-begging.

Comment: Yes, that is valid. Valid arguments can be question-begging. Any circular argument is question-begging but it is automatically valid. However, valid arguments, even simple syllogisms, may be informative and not question-begging. It all depends on the flow of justification or reasoning. In a question-begging argument you have no reason to accept the premises unless you already accept the conclusion. In a non-question-begging argument there is a flow of justification from the premises to the conclusion. You accept the conclusion because you accept the premises.

Comment: Circularity is not a logical fallacy. A therefore A is perfectly valid. It's considered as an informal fallacy because it's usually  a bad rhetorical argument, regardless MP is not circular unless Q = P

Comment: I think this is the crux of ['What the Tortoise Said to Achilles'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles#Explanation).

Answer (score 1):

> the first premise IF P THEN Q immediately implies conclusion Q.

This is wrong. (p → q) → q is not a tautology. Example:

p = it is raining

q = the ground is wet

That *if* it is raining *then* the ground is wet does not imply the ground is wet.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between modus ponens and the example you gave about god, is the presence of the word 'if', which means you are not assuming the conclusion. It is true that in modus ponens you assume the truth of the relationship between p and q, but that is not the same as assuming q. It might be clearer if you take an extreme example, for instance 'If I can travel at the speed of light, I can get to the moon in under a minute' is not assuming 'I can get to the moon in under a minute' is true.